# Problem with short date format in php

Tags: php, date, format

I have problem with date function in php. If I supply string in format "d.m.y" for example "01.01.01" it gets rendered as todays date which means that php gets confused.

I found:

> Note:
>
> The "Day, month and two digit year, with dots or tabs" format (dd [.\t] mm "." yy)
>   only works for the year values 61 (inclusive) to 99
>   (inclusive) - outside those years the time format "HH [.:] MM [.:] SS" has
>   precedence.

on: [php.net site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

How to override this behavior?

I know of date_create_from_format function which would work fine if I knew input will always be in format "d.m.y", but it won't.

UPDATE 1:

Code

```
$date = new DateTime('01.01.01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

outputs 2010-10-19 and I wanted 2001-01-01.

Comment: Why so much words in trying to describe what you did? Why not a single line of *the actual code?* date() function has nothing to do with formatted strings. So, whole question has no sense.

Comment: Also, for the record, your date mask of "dd.mm.yy" will print the day, month and year twice.  Correct mask is probably "d.m.y".

Comment: OP has a date `01.01.01` and wants to generate a timestamp from that. That doesn't work automatically because `strtotime` makes the `01.01` set the time instead of the date.

Comment: @Chris Henry: Outside of unix date formats, it is very common to describe formats with the symbols `d`, `m`, `y`, `h`, `m` and `s` where the number of those characters determines about the rendering. For example `yy` would be a two digit year, `yyyy` a four digit year, `d` a non-zero padded day and `dd` a zero padded day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getDateFromString( $str )
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd.m.y', $str );
    if ( $date !== false )
        return $date->getTimestamp();

    // you can try other common formats here
    // ...

    // otherwise just parse whatever there is
    return strtotime( $str );
}

echo date( 'd.m.Y H:i', getDateFromString( '01.01.01' ) ); // 01.01.2001 20:14
```

#### Edit

To adjust it a bit more to get your *exact* output:

```
function getDateTimeFromString( $str )
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd.m.y', $str );
    if ( $date !== false )
        return $date;

    // you can try other common formats here
    // ...

    // otherwise just parse whatever there is
    return new DateTime( $str );
}

$date = getDateTimeFromString( '01.01.01' );
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ); // 2001-01-01
```

Comment: I don't really like idea of doing testing myself for all possible formats, and I was more hoping to find easy php way. However I like your answer most.

Comment: Well, you don't have to test all possible formats, it's enough to check those that won't work with the normal `new DateTime( $str )`; and that shouldn't be that many different formats.

Comment: Only one problem remains, which I just discovered, and that is: On production server I have php 5.2.6 and DateTime::createFromFormat is not supported in that version.

Comment: @Milan: You can use `strptime` instead to parse a given date format and pass its results to `DateTime::setDate` or `mktime` to construct the date.

Comment: To the downvoters: Could you please be so kind to leave a reason why you downvote the answer? It's getting quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

To format a date other than now, use the second parameter. For example:

`echo date("d.m.y", 1255982665);`

echoes 19.10.09

Answer (score 1):

Just read the documentation! PHP's site is excellent

It seems like you want to reformat a date?

mktime() gives unix timestamp from component pieces
date() gives string from unixtimestamp (or implied now)
getdate() gives assoc array from unix timestamp

I think you want -

$arr = explode($dateIn, ':');  //get array [day, month, year]
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0, $arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]) //unix time stamp, a long integer representing time
date(DESIREDFORMAT, $timestamp);

check out the output formats here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: To quote OP: *“if I knew input will always be in format "dd.mm.yy", but it won't.”* – So your `explode` won't help.

Comment: Poke is right. Your solution does help in case of "." as delimiter. I would first have to find delimiter that is character that is not number and use it as explode parameter.